# New to RSpec, confused by new 3.x syntax and stubs

Tags: ruby, rspec, stubbing, rspec3

I'm trying to learn how to use RSpec, and the complexity of the subject combined with the general dearth of quality tutorials and the recent major syntactical overhaul has left me thoroughly stumped. I think I need to write a stub (not even sure about that to be honest), but I can't figure out how.

program being tested:

```
Class Session
  def initialize
    @interface = Interface.new
    @high_score = 1
    play
  end

  private
  def play
    get_high_score
  end

  def get_high_score
    score = @interface.get_high_score
    set_high_score(score)
  end

  def set_high_score
    high_score = (score.to_f/2).ceil
    @high_score = high_score
  end
end

class Interface
  def get_high_score
    puts "Best out of how many?"
    high_score = gets.chomp        
  end
end
```

Applicable test:

```
describe Session do
  describe "#new" do
    it "gets a high score" do
      session = Session.new
      session.set_high_score(3)
      expect(session.high_score).to eql(2)
    end
  end
end
```

This obviously doesn't work because it's a private method. The expectation is what it needs to be provided the set_high_score receives 3 as its argument, but I don't know how to get from the public initialization to setting it. I think I need to write a stub, but I can't figure out how that works exactly... It could also be some other more general faux pas... Not sure. I'm hoping someone can explain this stuff to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to stub your input - that is, your get. You can't get a handle to the Interface instance before you use it, and since you don't provide the means to inject an Interface dependency, you can use RSpec's `any_instance` expectation to mock responses from Interface objects.

As a note, in Ruby you typically eschew `get_x` and `set_x` accessors and getters in favor of `x` and `x=` methods.

```
class Session
  def initialize(interface = nil)
    @interface = Interface.new
    @high_score = 1
    play
  end

  private
  def play
    high_score
  end

  def high_score
    self.high_score = @interface.get_high_score
  end

  def high_score=(score)
    @high_score = (score / 2.0).ceil
  end
end

class Interface
  def get_high_score
    puts "Best out of how many?"
    gets.chomp.to_i
  end
end

describe Session do
  subject { Session.new }
  describe "#new" do
    it "gets a high score" do
      expect_any_instance_of(Interface).to receive(:get_high_score).and_return(3)
      expect(subject.high_score).to eql(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something funky, but that throws a private method error. 

`1) Session#new gets a high score
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.high_score).to eql(2)
     NoMethodError:
       private method 'high_score' called for #<Session:0x007ffd02a90b80>`

Also, could you elaborate on the x, x= methods comment?

Comment: The use of a stub in the 3x syntax with some familiar context was exactly what I needed for the most part. Thank you. Meanwhile however, if I change the x/x= methods as outlined above from `high_score` and `high_score=` to `high_score_i` and `high_score_i=(score)` (in order to differentiate the method from the attribute), the rest falls into place and it passes. I'm not sure how that jives with the x/x= comment though. Some insight into this aspect of your answer would be appreciated. Is there a name or some useful search term for the concept that would enable me to look deeper into it?

Comment: Are `high_score_i`, etc public? Accessing a method from a an rspec test is going to require it to be public (or you use `#send` with the private override flag). If you want to access `#high_score`, it'll need to be a public method. The naming shouldn't really matter though.

Comment: Not public. I essentially copied in your code, which failed with the snippet copied in my reply above. After a bit more fiddling, I changed the x/x= `high_score`s to high_score_is including the call in the play method, and that passed. That's what makes me think I'm not fully comprehending the x/x= convention you referenced.

Comment: x/x= is just conventionally used instead of get_x/set_x getters and setters like you'd see in Java; no special magic in them.